# Center icon over image with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know this can be achieved using the absolute method, but just wondering if there is a Flexbox execution of a centered icon over an image (that way you have have the flexibility of different sized icons).

I can do it with background image but is there a way to do it using the `img` tag?

```
<div class="container">
    <i class="icon-class"></i>
</div>

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: url(img.jpg) 50% / 100px;
}
```

The only thing I have come up with so far is:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="img.jpg" width="100" class="img">
    <i class="icon"></i>
</div>

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}

.icon {
    z-index:1;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Flex-boxes are the contrast to this, what you want to achieve. They are for the layout of different boxes side-by-side. They try to adjust these boxes in that way, that they do **not** overlap.

Comment: what you are missing is size on container and position:relative to trigger z-index on icon